# How to print out the current working directory of gdal package in python?

Tags: python, gdal

I have searched around and have not seen a way to print out the current working directory for the gdal package in Python at all in Stackoverflow. Is there a method that I am missing? I did not see any method related to current working directory for gdal's python package at https://gdal.org/api/python.html

I was trying to call the gdal.warp(xxx, xxx), but it shows input file type is invalid.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: If you meant "the directory that gdal is installed in", do `import gdal` then `gdal.__file__` like any other package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import gdal` then `gdal.__file__` like any other package from user `smci` is actually the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A process has only one current working directory at a time. So you can just use

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```